# Replacing laravel blade with vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have an existing laravel blade template and am rewriting it using Vue components inside the blade template.
For example, one existing line in the blade template is:

`<button class="btn-remove" onclick="removeItem('{{ $item->id }}', this);"></button>`

This references a php function called `removeItem`.
Is there a way to call the php function in the new Vue component or do I have to redo the php function into javascript?

Comment: What is removeItem? I don't think this is a "php function" according to your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean that the template references a function `removeItem` that is defined somewhere in the JS scripts that run with your blade.

If you are migrating the whole blade into a VueJs Instance, you'll need to move the methods that are used by the Vue component into its ViewModel definition.

**You would also need to pass any data coming from `PHP` as a `prop` or fetch it from an API** So that the component can have access to it after its rendered.

For your example, the component would look something like this (using a prop).

```
Vue.component('MyComponent', {
    template:  `
        <div>
            <button class="btn-remove" @click="removeItem"></button>
        </div>
    `,
    props: {
        itemId: String
    },
    methods: {
        removeItem() {
            // Handle click event
            this.$emit('remove', this.itemId); // for example
        }
    }
})
```

And in your blade file, you would replace with:

```
<MyComponent item-id="{{$item->id}}"/>
```

Vue will replace the template above with the template specified in your component, and the PHP "bindings" will be passed as text into your HTML.

Comment: thanks Daniel.  The only instance of `removeFromCart` is a php function inside the account controller:   
`public function removeFromCart(CartRemoveFormRequest $request) { logic here}`

Comment: You will probably need to expose that through an API endpoint